# Rounting for multiple NIC, wrong order route sometimes

Tags: networking, server, routing

I make a clean install of ubuntu server 17.04, have 3 nic, this serve many services like (SAMBA, postgres, LAMPP, openvpn etc.) and sometime all work fine and other time no, for some reason thath i don't know on boot time exchange the order in the last two row of route table.

```
*Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.X.X.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s31f6
10.X.X.0        10.X.X.2        255.X.X.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.X.X.2        0.0.0.0         255.X.X.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.X.X.0    172.X.X.5    255.X.X.252 UG    0      0        0 enp2s0
172.X.X.4    0.X.X.0         255.X.X.252 U     0      0        0 enp2s0
localnet        0.X.X.0         255.X.X.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s31f6
localnet        0.X.X.0         255.X.X.0   U     0      0        0 enp6s0*
```

WRONG!!!

and other times

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.X.X.0         192.X.X.254   0.X.X.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s31f6
10.X.X.0        10.X.X.2        255.X.X.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.X.X.2        0.X.X.0         255.X.X.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
172.X.X.4    0.X.X.0         255.X.X.252 U     0      0        0 enp2s0
192.X.X.0     0.X.X.0         255.X.X.0   U     0      0        0 enp6s0
192.X.X.0     0.X.X.0         255.X.X.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s31f6
```

WORK FINE ALL SERVICE.

My interface

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
    address 192.X.X.245
    netmask 255.X.X.0
    network 192.X.X.0
    broadcast 192.X.X.255
    gateway 192.X.X.254
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 186.X.X.X 186.X.X.X

# LAN
auto enp0s6
iface enpXXX inet static
    address 192.X.X.2
    netmask 255.X.X.0
    network 192.X.X.0
    broadcast 192.X.X.255

# VPN
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
    address 172.X.X.6
netmask 255.X.X.252
network 127.X.X.4
broadcast 172.X.X.7
up route add -net 10.X.X.0/30 gw 172.X.X.5 dev enp2s0
```

Someone know the problem or solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found is remove de network from dynamic route in interfaces file just after definition of enp0s31f6
"post-up route del -net 192.168.1.0/24 gw 0.0.0.0 dev enp0s31f6"

isn't elegance solution but ...

thanks anyway!!